# Help with determining the nature of the Sum: $\sum_{j=2}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{j-\sqrt{j}}$ when n goes to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I am struggling with finding the nature of this series:

$\sum_{j=2}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{j-\sqrt{j}}$

I tried to prove its absolute convergent, but I failed.
The hint in the book indicates the Dirichlet theorem, but I find it irrelevant.

I'd appreciate your help; and thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the alternating series test.

Comment: Do you mean Leibniz’s Test?
Completly forgot about that one. It works.

Comment: The given "series" is in fact a finite sum. Do we have to look at the limit of the given expression when $n$ goes to infinity?

Comment: Yes, when n goes to infinity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Leibniz’s Test:
The alternating series $\sum_{n>0} (-1)^{n}b_n$ is convergent if $\{b_n\}$ is a nonincreasing sequence of positive terms converging to $0$.

Here, $b_n = \frac{1}{n - \sqrt{n}}$

We can see that $b_n$ is a nonincreasing sequence of positive terms converging to $0$.

So, the series $\sum_{j=2}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{j-\sqrt j}$
is convergent, when $n$ goes to infinity.

Answer (score 2):

Let us compute the contribution to the series of two consecutive terms.
The first term is for some odd $m$ and comes with plus, the next term is for the even $(m+1)$ and comes with minus.

For the sake of convergence we may and do neglect some first terms in the series, so let us consider only values $m>10$.
The contribution of them is:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac 1{m-\sqrt m} -
\frac 1{m +1-\sqrt {m+1}} 
&=
\frac{(m +1-\sqrt {m+1}) - (m-\sqrt m)}{(m-\sqrt m)(m +1-\sqrt {m+1})}
\\
&=
\frac {1-\frac {(m+1)-m}{\sqrt {m+1}+\sqrt m}}{\sqrt{m(m+1)}(\sqrt m-1)(\sqrt{m+1}-1)}
\\
&=
\frac {1-\frac 1{\sqrt {m+1}+\sqrt m}}{\sqrt{m(m+1)}(\sqrt m-1)(\sqrt{m+1}-1)}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
This expression above is between $\frac{ 1-\frac1{3+3}}{\sqrt{m+1}^4}$ (there is less in the numerator and more in the denominator) and $\frac 1{(\sqrt m-1)^4}$ (there is now more in the numerator and less in the denominator). So grouping in these manner the terms we obtain (after neglecting some few finitely many terms) a series of contributions for odd $m$ which can be compared with $\frac 1{m^2}$. This not only shows the convergence, but also shows how quickly / slowly this happens.